# SFML - Sprite is blank after loading from texture

Tags: c++, graphics, textures, sprite, sfml

I am using SFML to display a sprite on the screen. I first use a texture and call loadFromFile() to load the image. This works well with no errors occurring. It seems that the image path is correct and it loads the image, but it doesn't seem to store the data in the sprite. The sprite is displayed without error, but it shows a blank white image.

Is there a problem with my code in the following snippets? They should be fairly easy to read :).

My code:

Main.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Menu.h"

using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    VideoMode vm = VideoMode::getDesktopMode();
    int width = vm.width, height = vm.height;
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(width, height), "Score Arena v1.0", Style::Fullscreen);
    window.setPosition(Vector2i(0, 0));

    Menu menu(width, height);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch (event.type) {
                case Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;

                //when a key is pressed
                case Event::KeyPressed:
                    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape))
                        window.close();
                    break;
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        
        menu.draw(window);

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Menu.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

class Menu {
        int page = 0;
        string title = "Score Arena";
        string labels[4]{
                "Single Player",
                "Multi Player",
                "Options",
                "Exit"
        };
        Sprite background;

        int width, height;

public:
        Menu(int, int);
        void draw(RenderWindow &window);
};
```

Menu.cpp

```
#include "Menu.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

Menu::Menu(int width, int height) {
        this->width = width;
        this->height = height;

        Texture bg;
        if (!bg.loadFromFile("menuBg.jpg"))
                std::cout << "Error loading image!" << std::endl;
        background.setTexture(bg);
}

void Menu::draw(RenderWindow &window) {
        window.draw(background, RenderStates::Default);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `sf::Sprite` object doesn't internally copy the passed `sf::Texture` object when you call the `setTexture()` member function. An `sf::Sprite` just refers to an `sf::Texture`; the former doesn't own the latter. The associated `sf::Texture` must exist when you render the `sf::Sprite`.

It is stated in the documentation for [`sf::Sprite`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Sprite.php#details):

> It is important to note that the `sf::Sprite` instance doesn't copy the
> texture that it uses, it only keeps a reference to it. Thus, a
> `sf::Texture` must not be destroyed while it is used by a `sf::Sprite`
> (i.e. never write a function that uses a local `sf::Texture` instance
> for creating a sprite).

The problem is in your `Menu`'s constructor:

```
Menu::Menu(int width, int height) {
        this->width = width;
        this->height = height;

        Texture bg; // <-- it is local variable !!!
        if (!bg.loadFromFile("menuBg.jpg"))
                std::cout << "Error loading image!" << std::endl;
        background.setTexture(bg); // <-- associating sprite to a local object!!!
        // bg goes out of existence!!!
}
```

The `sf::Texture` object, `bg`, ceases to exist as soon the program control flow leaves the constructor because `bg` is a local variable inside the constructor. As a result, the `sf::Sprite` object, `background` – a `Menu` *data member* – outlives its associated `sf::Texture` object, `bg` – a local object.

Then, in `Menu::draw()` you use this `sf::Sprite` object, `background`, which internally refers to an `sf::Texture` object that no longer exists:

```
void Menu::draw(RenderWindow &window) {
        window.draw(background, RenderStates::Default);
}
```

#### Possible Solution

Instead of the `sf::Texture` object being a *local object* in `Menu`'s constructor, you could make it a *data member* of `Menu`:

```
class Menu {
        // ...
        Texture bg;
        Sprite background;
        // ...
};
```

This way, `Menu` owns `bg` (in contrast to `Menu`'s constructor owning `bg` as was the case before), and therefore `Menu` controls `bg`'s lifetime: `bg` is kept alive while the `Menu` object lives. This time, when you call `Menu::draw()`, the `sf::Sprite` object does refer to a living `sf::Texture` object.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! I made Texture bg a member of Menu.h so it no longer gets destroyed! Great answer!